# Replace values of a column based on another column having as input a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

With the `base::replace` function I want to change some values of column `z` based on the values of column `y`

```r
library(tidyverse)

(df <- tibble(y = 10:13, z = 20:23))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       y     z
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1    10    20
#> 2    11    21
#> 3    12    22
#> 4    13    23
```

I have the data.frame `val` where column `a` the value to be used as condition and column `b` will be the replacement value.

```r
(val <- tibble(a = c(10, 12), b = c(100, 200)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10   100
#> 2    12   200
```

Using the following approach it is possible to get the desired result, but it only works if **all** the values inside `val` are inside `df`

```r
df %>% mutate(z = replace(z, y %in% val$a, val$b))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       y     z
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1    10   100
#> 2    11    21
#> 3    12   200
#> 4    13    23
```

For example, if I update `val` to have values that are **not** in `df`, then:

```r
(val <- tibble(a = c(1, 10, 12), b = c(1, 100, 200)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2    10   100
#> 3    12   200
```

and I run the code again ...

```r
df %>% mutate(z = replace(z, y %in% val$a, val$b))
#> Warning in x[list] <- values: number of items to replace is not a multiple of
#> replacement length
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       y     z
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1    10     1
#> 2    11    21
#> 3    12   100
#> 4    13    23
```

There are errors ... How can I fix this?

<sup>Created on 2021-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need any `map`as 'a', 'b' and the number of rows of 'df' have the same length.  So, an elementwise comparison with `==` can be done.  Instead of `replace`, it may be better with `ifelse/case_when` etc as `replace` `values` should be of the same length as the `list` condition TRUE elements

```
library(dpyr)
df %>%
    mutate(z = case_when(a == y ~ as.integer(b), TRUE ~ z))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      y     z
#  <int> <int>
#1    10   100
#2    11   200
#3    12    22
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$z <- with(df, ifelse(a == y, b, z))
```

---

In the OP's code, there is a difference in `length` when we do

```
 replace(x = z, y == .x, values = .y)
```

where 'z' will be the full column length, `.x` , `.y` will be each row element

#### Update

Based on the updated data, we could a join and then use `coalesce`

```
df %>% 
    left_join(val, by = c('y' = 'a')) %>%
    transmute(y, z = coalesce(b, z))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#      y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    10   100
#2    11    21
#3    12   200
#4    13    23
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. I assumed it was a good use case for the map family, but elementwise comparison with case_when is effective.

Comment: Although it doesn't work if my original data.frame is not the same length as the data.frame containing the replacements, but it is something I forgot to put in the reprex. I'm sorry.

Comment: @William Please update your example. thanks

Answer (score 3):

One possibility might be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(z = coalesce(b[match(y, a)], z))

      y     z
  <int> <dbl>
1    10   100
2    11   200
3    12    22
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `replace`

```
transform(
  df,
  z = replace(z, na.omit(match(y, a)), b[na.omit(match(y, a))])
)
```

gives

```
   y   z
1 10 100
2 11 200
3 12  22
```